# NullPointerException on findViewById on fragment replacement

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have an activity, say `A`, which has a fragment with a textview called `TotalTimerFragment` which contains a `countdowntimer`. There are 2 other fragments called `F1` and `F2`. Activity `A` adds `F1` and the `countdowntimer` in fragment `TotalTimerFragment` starts. After a few seconds `F1` is replaced by `F2`. And here the `countdowntimer` should continue for few more seconds. But it crashes and gives a `NullPointerException` for the findViewById in the OnTick method in the class.

Here is the code for the FT fragment: `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.total_timer_textview)` in `onTick` method gives `NullPointerException`

```
public class TotalTimerFragment extends Fragment{
    TextView totalWorkoutTimer;
    TotalTimeCounter timeCounter;
    static long total_millis;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_totaltimer, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        totalWorkoutTimer = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.total_timer_textview);
    }

    public class TotalTimeCounter extends CountDownTimer {
        TextView totalWorkoutTimer;

        public TotalTimeCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            total_millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String total_hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(total_millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(total_millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.
                        MILLISECONDS.toHours(total_millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(total_millis) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(total_millis)));
            totalWorkoutTimer = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.total_timer_textview);
            totalWorkoutTimer.setText(total_hms);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you call this TotalTimeCounter class?

Comment: Who does total_time_textview belong to? That is, is it in the activity's layout or the fragments layout?

Comment: @ Mohit, TotalTimeCounter class is invoked by activity A through an interface. This part is working

Comment: @Kaylwin, the total_time_textview belongs to fragment_totaltimer.xml inflated by the fragment TotalTimerFragment

Comment: Try answer by Mohit Suthar, you need this `totalWorkoutTimer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total_timer_textview);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

> totalWorkoutTimer = (TextView)
>   getActivity().findViewById(R.id.total_timer_textview);

Causing issue because `total_timer_textview` TextView is inside Fragment layout but accessing it `getActivity()` method which return context of Activity.

Use `view` first parameter of `onViewCreated` method like:

```
totalWorkoutTimer = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.total_timer_textview);
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion solved the problem. I would have never thought of using the view in onViewCreated.

Comment: Although now the views of my other fragments are getting merged for some reason. I had tried using getView() on the fragment and then using it. But that didn't work. Can you elaborate a bit on how your suggestion works? I can learn something valuable. Thanks

Comment: `other fragments are getting merged` means?

Comment: When fragment A is replaced by fragment B, Fragment B is overlapping A but not replacing. Looks like both are simultaneously attached. During my previous trials (before using countdowntimer) the replacing was occurring properly

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fragment and your textview inside your layout than you should use `view` instead of `getActivity()`

```
totalWorkoutTimer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total_timer_textview);
```

And seems to you are not calling timer class, you can try this

```
     public class TotalTimerFragment extends Fragment{
    TextView totalWorkoutTimer;
    TotalTimeCounter timeCounter;
    static long total_millis;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_totaltimer, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        totalWorkoutTimer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total_timer_textview);
//Call your count down timer class///
    }

    public class TotalTimeCounter extends CountDownTimer {

        public TotalTimeCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            total_millis = millisUntilFinished;
            String total_hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(total_millis),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(total_millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.
                            MILLISECONDS.toHours(total_millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(total_millis) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(total_millis)));
            totalWorkoutTimer.setText(total_hms);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am calling the TotalTimerClass through the Fragments using an interface

Comment: What way do you suggest I use the view? Where and how should I declare it? I have tried one method using view, it solves the problem, but some other issues arise. Hence, I am asking for your suggestions.

Methods used: 1) using the view in the onCreatedView and 2) declaring a view = TotalTimerFragment.super.getView() inside the TotalTimeCounter class

Answer (score 1):

You must need textview  with id of total_timer_textview in your fragment xml file as well

Comment: What makes you think OP didn't have `total_timer_textview` in the layout?